# Set public class variable in constructor

Tags: c++, class, variables

I want to write a public class variable with a value that is given when the constructor is called. I have a solution that I thought was correct until someone told me it might be wrong (the line with "Foo::alpha = alpha;").
So when I run

```
Foo bar(g, 0);
bar.run();
```

then I want that the value 0 is written to the class variable so I can access it later in the run method.

Foo.h

```
class Foo: public Framework::Centrality {
public:
    double alpha;
    Foo(const Graph& G, double alpha=1);
    void run() override;
};
```

Foo.cpp

```
Foo::Foo(const Graph& G, double alpha) : Centrality(G) {
    if (alpha >= 0 && alpha <= 1) {
        Foo::alpha = alpha;
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("...");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it might be wrong"?

Comment: @Ashish: Why do you say that? What makes you think the OP doesn't know "OOP principles" or that he/she needs them?

Comment: What's your question, by the way?

Comment: @Ashish: In what way is data encapsulation "being violated"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, keeping class variable as public violates it, anyone from outside can directly access it.

Comment: @Ashish: I see no reason for a `private` member and a series of thin getters/setters in this case. Can you tell me what that reason is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What you're doing is fine.**

Some people may claim that `Foo::alpha` looks like it names a static member and may therefore be confusing, but my response to that is that such people would only think so because they do not know C++.

`Foo::alpha` unambiguously names the member `alpha` in the class `Foo`; since you're in a member function, that member can be (and is) a non-`static` member.

It would be more conventional to write `this->alpha` or rename the constructor argument, but what you're doing is fine.

Comment: I think you know C++, and thanks for specifying all the details, thanks for sharing your knowledge, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is technically correct, but you should really use the member initialization list for this:

```
#include <stdexcept>

class Base {};

class Ace :  Base
{
  public:
    Ace(double alpha = 0) : Base(), alpha(alpha)
    {
      if(alpha < 0 || alpha > 1)
        throw std::runtime_error("");
    }
    double alpha;
}
```

You can use a different name for the constructor parameter `alpha`, but it is not required by the language.

Comment: Yes in general, but it's only a `double`, and your version strips out the range check.

Comment: The range check can be performed in the constructor body, which also makes for cleaner code in the end.

Comment: @Ashish: Hurray, cargo-cult programming. Awesome.

Comment: Oh, dang, missed that in the question, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply assign the value to `alpha` using `this->` without using `Foo::`:

```
Foo::Foo(const Graph& G, double alpha) : Centrality(G) {
    if (alpha >= 0 && alpha <= 1) {
        this->alpha = alpha;
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("...");
    }
}
```

`Foo::` is *usually* used to access static variables or methods or to refer to a method of the class during the implementation. Your code is not incorrect, but usually it's not used to initialise a non-static member public variable.

Comment: Yes, but what's wrong with the original approach, as asked by OP?

Comment: Thanks, I will try _this->_. So does using Foo:: in a non-static context lead to a wrong result or is just messy?

Comment: @FirePrism It's not necesarily messy, its just personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

It's not wrong.  It's just not pretty.  When the constructor's parameter has the same name as a data member on the class, you have a few options:

1)  Use the member initializer list, which according to the standard, must do what you're intending for it to do here:

```
Foo::Foo(const Graph& G, double alpha) :
    Centrality(G), alpha(alpha)
{
    if(alpha < 0 || alpha > 1)
        throw std::runtime_error("...");
}
```

2)  Fully qualify the member alpha, as you are doing:

```
Foo::Foo(const Graph& G, double alpha) :
    Centrality(G)
{
    if(alpha >= 0 && alpha <=1 )
        Foo::alpha = alpha;
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("...");
}
```

3)  Use the `this` pointer to specify the member:

```
Foo::Foo(const Graph& G, double alpha) :
    Centrality(G)
{
    if(alpha >= 0 && alpha <=1 )
        this->alpha = alpha;
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("...");
}
```

4)  Name them something different.  A common convention is to prefix the names of data members with m or m_:

```
class Foo : public Framework::Centrality
{
    /* other stuff */

 private:
    double m_Alpha;
};


Foo::Foo(const Graph& G, double alpha) :
    Centrality(G)
{
    if(alpha >= 0 && alpha <=1 )
        m_Alpha = alpha;
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("...");
}
```

Another common thing I see is prefixing the paramter in the cpp with an underscore:

```
class Foo : public Framework::Centraliy
{
    Foo(const Graph& G, double alpha=1);
};

Foo::Foo(const Graph& G, double _alpha) :
    Centrality(G)
{
    ...
}
```

5)  Or if using the pImpl idiom, (I like to name my Impl member `m`):

```
class Foo : public Framework::Centrality
{
    /* other stuff */

 private:
    struct Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> m;
};

// In foo.cpp
struct Foo::Impl
{
    double alpha;
}

Foo::Foo(const Graph& G, double alpha) :
    Centrality(G),
    m(make_unique<Impl>())
{
    if(alpha >= 0 && alpha <=1 )
        m->alpha = alpha;
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("...");
}
```